# 403 org_internal Error with branded YouTube channel on GSuite API Credentials

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-workspace

We have a client_secret setted-up for blocking non-organization users from access on our internal CRM.
Using the same client credentials, we will wish to be able to upload videos, through our CRM, directly on our official Brand YouTube channel.
There is a problem though: linked to the main GSuite organization account, there are two youtube channels, one nominal and one branded.
Trying to generate a token for uploading videos on the main branded channel, through our client_secret, during the authentication phase the API responds with:

```
Errore 403: org_internal
This client is restricted to users within its organization.
Richiedi dettagli
access_type=offline
o2v=1
response_type=code
redirect_uri=https://CRM_DOMAIN/oauth2callback
client_id=***
prompt=consent
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

So the question is: how to behave in this situation? Is it possible to link the branded channel directly to the GSuite organization without losing the name? 
I tried to move the Brand channel by connecting it directly within my GSuite organization, but the channel is renamed with my name and no longer with the brand name, making it impossible for me to change the channel name because the Name and Surname fields are mandatory.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever work out a way to associate your brand account to your organisation? I'm currently having the same issue. Thanks